# why there appeared error "InvalidParamsError: The data variable "volume_m3_min_h" is not known. " in jupyter notebook which running oggm model code?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, dependencies

I'm encountering an error while running some code in Jupyter Notebook using the OGGM (Open Global Glacier Model) library. The specific error message I'm getting is:
InvalidParamsError: The data variable 'volume_m3_min_h' is not known. Is it new or is it a new dimension? Check comment above this raise for more info!
I'm using OGGM version 1.5 in my Jupyter Notebook environment.

The code that triggers the error is as follows:
ds = utils.compile_run_output(gdirs, input_filesuffix='_historical')
(ds.volume.sum(dim='rgi_id') * 1e-9).plot(label='_my_spinup')
I have already checked the dataset and ensured that the 'volume_m3_min_h' variable is present. However, it seems that the code is unable to recognize or access this variable correctly.Could you please help me understand the possible causes for this error and suggest potential solutions? Are there any changes or updates in OGGM v1.5 that could affect the usage of this code? Is there a different way to access the 'volume_m3_min_h' variable in the latest version of OGGM?
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!